# Multiple list of figures/tables for appendices with KOMA script

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, appendices

I have two appendices. The first one contains only tables, while the second one has tables, figures and schemes. At the begin of each appendix I want the list of tables/figures to show up. I know how to do this, if there is only one list of tables/figures for the whole appendix. I followed [Markus Kohm's guideline](https://komascript.de/comment/5578#comment-5578) for that. This works fine with a single list, but not with my modifications for multiple lists. In addition for the second appendix, I want the tables, figures and schemes listed combined in one "appendix B list".

So, what I want it to look like is this:

> **Appendix A**
>
> *Content*
>
> Table A.1 Table in Appendix A
>
> Table A.2 Table in Appendix A
>
> **Appendix B**
>
> *Content*
>
> Table B.1 Table in Appendix B
>
> Figure B.1 Figure in Appendix B
>
> Scheme B.1 Scheme in Appendix B
>
> Table B.2 Table in Appendix B

This is what I thought should work, but which does not give the desired output:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\newcommand{\entrynumberwithprefix}[2]{%
    \csname listof#1entryname\endcsname\ #2%
}%
\newlength{\loftnumwidth}
\setlength{\loftnumwidth}{5em}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{lot},
    numwidth=\loftnumwidth,%
    indent=0pt,
]{tocline}{table}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{lof},
    numwidth=\loftnumwidth,%
    indent=0pt,
]{tocline}{figure}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
    type=scheme,%
    types=schemes,%
    float,%
    floattype=4,% 
    name=Scheme,%
    tocentrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{los},
    tocentrynumwidth=\loftnumwidth,%
    tocentryindent=0pt,
]{los}

% new lists for appendices
\DeclareNewTOC[%
    listname={Content of Appendix A},%
]{lotA}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
    listname={Tables in Appendix B},%
]{lotB}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
    listname={Content of Appendix B},%
]{lofB}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
    listname={Schemes in Appendix B},%
]{losB}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\useappendixtocs}{%
    \setcounter{figure}{0}%
    \setcounter{table}{0}%
    \KOMAoptions{listof=leveldown}
    \renewcommand*{\ext@table}{lotA}%
    \renewcommand*{\ext@figure}{lotB}%
    \renewcommand*{\ext@figure}{lofB}%
    \renewcommand*{\ext@figure}{losB}%
}
\g@addto@macro\appendix{
    \useappendixtocs
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofschemes

\chapter{Main Document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Table in main document.}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure in main document.}
\end{figure}

\begin{scheme}
    \caption{Scheme in main document.}
\end{scheme}

\appendix
\chapter{First appendix with tables only}
\listoftoc{lotA}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Table in appendix A.}
\end{table}


\chapter{Second appendix with figures, tables and schemes}
\listoftoc{lofB}%

\begin{table}
    \caption{Table in appendix B.}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure in appendix B.}
\end{figure}

\begin{scheme}
    \caption{Scheme in appendix B.}
\end{scheme}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Table in appendix B.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `scrbook` loads package `tocbasic` automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```
\documentclass[
  listof=totoc,
  listof=flat% <- added
]{scrbook}

\newcommand{\entrynumberwithprefix}[2]{%
    \csname listof#1entryname\endcsname\ #2%
}%

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{lof}
]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{lot}
]{tocline}{table}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=scheme,%
  types=schemes,
  float,%
  floattype=4,%
  name=Scheme,%
  tocentryentrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{los},% <- option name changed
  counterwithin=chapter,% <- added
]{los}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofapp{%
  \DeclareNewTOC[%
    listname={Content of Appendix \thechapter},%
    setup=leveldown% <- needs KOMA-Script version 3.25
  ]{app\thechapter}%
  \unsettoc{app\thechapter}{totoc}%
  \renewcommand{\ext@figure}{app\thechapter}%
  \renewcommand{\ext@table}{app\thechapter}%
  \renewcommand{\ext@scheme}{app\thechapter}%
  \listoftoc{app\thechapter}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofschemes

\chapter{Main Document}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Table in main document.}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Figure in main document.}
\end{figure}
\begin{scheme}
  \caption{Scheme in main document.}
\end{scheme}

\appendix
\chapter{First appendix with tables only}
\listofapp
\begin{table}
  \caption{Table in appendix A.}
\end{table}

\chapter{Second appendix with figures, tables and schemes}
\listofapp
\begin{table}
  \caption{Table in appendix B.}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Figure in appendix B.}
\end{figure}
\begin{scheme}
  \caption{Scheme in appendix B.}
\end{scheme}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Table in appendix B.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that option `setup` for `\DeclareNewTOC` is introduced in KOMA-Script version 3.25. With former KOMA-Script versions you have to remove it and to add `\setuptoc{app\thechapter}{leveldown}`.

Comment: Thank you! I get error message for `setup=leveldown` in your code. But it works when I comment it out and add it with `\KOMAoptions`. I'd like to thank you for your improvements of my code, too. I didn't know that `flat` can be applied to LoFT. I added it to the definition of `listofapp`, because I have already set `listof=graduated` to have a graduated ToC. (I left it out in the MWE.) I also recognized the warning to `tocentrynumberformat`, but thought this is a bug, because `tocentryentrynumberformat` seemed odd to me.

Comment: `setup=leveldown` was introduced in KOMA-Script version 3.25 (current on CTAN and in MiKTeX2.9 and TL2018pretest). `listof=gratuated` only affects lists with `owner=float` like LOF, LOT and the new defined TOCs  by `\DeclareNewTOC` (because `owner=float` is default). If you want to have a graduated TOC use `toc=gratuated`, but this is the default setting.

Comment: I just had a look in KOMA documentation. I can use `toc=graduated` and your suggestion with `listof=flat` to get seperate designs for ToC and LoFT.

Comment: Option `entrynumberformat` of `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` can be used by `\RedeclareSectionCommand` etc. with prefix `toc` as `tocentrynumberformat` and by `DeclareNewTOC` with prefix `tocentry` which results in `tocentryentrynumberformat` ;-)

Comment: Thank you! Concerning KOMA version. I freshly installed TeXlive 2017. It has KOMA 3.24 and says `no updates available`. I think updates might be frozen before release of TeXlive2018 in June or so??? I will check the option with the new version again as soon as I have it.

Comment: Yes, TL 2017 was frozen with KOMA-Script version 3.24.