# Splitting List of Figures/Tables between main document and appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, appendix

I have figures/tables in the main part of my thesis as well as in the appendix.
Current status: All figures/tables are now in the LoF (List of Figures)/LoT (List of Tables).

I want to have different LoFs/LoTs:

a) LoF and LoT for the figures and tables of the main part. (At the very beginning of the thesis)
b) Then also a LoF and a LoT for the figures and tables of the appendix (Right after the part/section 'Appendix').

```
\documentclass[a4paper,header]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage{textcomp}                       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
\usepackage[english]{babel}     
\usepackage{ragged2e}                                               
\usepackage{booktabs}                                               
\usepackage[section]{placeins}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[format=hang,
            justification=RaggedRight,              
            singlelinecheck=off,                        
            labelfont=bf,                                   
            font=footnotesize,
            textfont=footnotesize,
            twoside,
            labelsep=colon
            ]{caption}  
                                    
\usepackage[language=autobib,
    backend=biber                               %%%% switch on/off 
    ]{biblatex}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[
toc,
page,
title,
titletoc,
header
]{appendix}
%%%
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendix}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures %%% only the first two pictures
%\listoftables %%% only tables of the main part (currently no tables)

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First  Section}

Hello.

\begin{figure}[htb] 
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{example-image-main-part-1}
\end{figure} 


\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{example-image-main-part-2}
\end{figure} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{appendices}

%%% here I would like to see the LoF and LoT for the figures/tables of the appendix) %%%

\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.\arabic{figure}}

\begin{figure}[htb] 
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{example-image-appendix-1}
\end{figure} 


\begin{figure}[htb] 
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{example-image-appendix-2}
\end{figure} 


\begin{figure}[htb] 
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{example-image-appendix-3}
\end{figure} 


\end{appendices}



\end{document}
```

[image]

I thank you so much for your support.

Comment: Could this [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130159/splitting-list-of-figures) provide an answer to your problem? or [this (using the koma class)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427913/multiple-list-of-figures-tables-for-appendices-with-koma-script?rq=1)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686939/make-a-table-of-contents-specific-to-appendix-article-class-and-display-appen/686973?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C18.0186#686973

Comment: It worked - thank you @MikeEhrmantraut

Comment: I managed to get a 'List of Figures' and a 'List of Tables' right after the 'Table of Content' (and also in the appendix for the tables and figures in the appendix). Unfortunately, the LoF and LoT have the wrong header () - it is still 'Table of Content' instead of 'List of Figures' and 'List of Tables'. Any idea to change this?